# setcookie nao funciona

Tags: php

Boas eu tenho o seguinte código php que cria uma cookie pelo que quando faço echo desta este nao imprime nada na tela e o resultado da procura na DB esta bem porque diz que o $resultado tem um array e por isso entra no if.

```
 $nomenecessario=$_GET['ref'];
$count=$_POST['nivelacessos'];
 if ($conn->query("UPDATE subditos SET niveis_acesso_id='$count' WHERE 
    id='$nomenecessario'") === TRUE){ 
 //Buscar na tabela usuario o usuário que corresponde com os dados digitado 
   no formulário
    $result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM subditos WHERE id='$nomenecessario' LIMIT 1";
    $resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
    $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);

    //Encontrado um usuario na tabela usuário com os mesmos dados digitado no formulário
    if(isset($resultado)){
        $cookie_email = $resultado['email'];
        setcookie($cookie_emailu, $cookie_email, time() + (86400 * 30), "/"); // 86400 = 1 day


           echo $_COOKIE[$cookie_emailu];
            $rer=0;
      //   echo "<script>   setTimeout(window.location='../',0);</script>"; 



}
}
```

Comment: Acho que precisa atualizar a página para aparecer, o cookie vai ser criado depois do próximo carregamento;

Comment: eu tento utilizar a cookie noutra pagina e tambem nao funciona, simplesmente acho que ele nao esta a criar a cookie

Comment: Da para ver se foi criado no "Inspecionar Elemento > Storage > Cookies", caso não encontrar pode ser que seu navegador ou o S.O. esteja bloqueando

Comment: Geralmente utilizo somente 
setcookie("dados", serialize($dados), time() + 3600 * 24 * 365);

Comment: Por mim seu código está correto, se $cookie_emailu e $cookie_email for uma string

Comment: pois mas nem utilizando $_SESSION resulta, eu quero passar as coisas para outra pagina e nao consigo

Comment: Se for usar $_SESSION não esqueça do session_start(); antes de tudo tudo tudo.

Comment: eu sei, começo a achar que é problema do servidor porque isto nao tem problemas e estou encalhado num problema de principiante

Comment: No caso não precisa usar $_SESSION para passar para outra página, como você definiu o Cookie ele ficará salvo no navegador até que o tempo dele expirar ou você remove-lo

Comment: eu sei o problema é que ele nao fica guardado no cookie

Answer (score 2):

Nada como um exemplo minimo e reduzido. Olhando na documentação do [php](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setcookie.php)  tem dois problemas principais que podem acontecer. Alguma coisa ser impressa antes da chamada de `setcookie()`, fazendo com que a chamada à função retorne `false`. Ou pode ser que o cookie criado esteja limitado a um subdiretorio especifico (o quarto parametro da função `setcookie()` serve para indicar em que diretorios o cookie sera visivel). Partindo desse dois problemas crie essa estrutura de pastas para exemplificar:

```
/(raiz)
    index.php
    DiretorioA
        a.php
    DiretorioB
        b.php
```

O arquivo **index.php** tem o seguinte conteudo:

```
<?php
//Diretorio raiz '/index.php'

if(!isset($_COOKIE['cookie_na_raiz'])){
    $status = setcookie("cookie_na_raiz", 
    'Este cookie foi criado na raiz do site', time()+3600);

    if($status){
    echo 'Cookie criado com sucesso';
    }else{
        echo 'Erro ao criar cookie';
    }
}

var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

Conteudo de **a.php**:

```
<?php
//Diretorio a '/DiretorioA/a.php'

if(!isset($_COOKIE['cookie_na_pasta_a'])){
    $status = setcookie("cookie_na_pasta_a", 
    'Este cookie foi criado na pasta a', time()+3600, '/');

    if($status){
    echo 'Cookie criado com sucesso';
    }else{
        echo 'Erro ao criar cookie';
    }
}

var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

E por fim conteudo de **b.php**:

```
<?php
//Diretorio b '/DiretorioB/b.php'

if(!isset($_COOKIE['cookie_na_pasta_b'])){
    $status = setcookie("cookie_na_pasta_b", 
    'Este cookie foi criado na pasta b', time()+3600);

    if($status){
    echo 'Cookie criado com sucesso';
    }else{
        echo 'Erro ao criar cookie';
    }
}

var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

Execute cada um dos arquivos (não importa a sequencia) só para criar os cookies.

Quando você acessar o arquivo **index.php** (depois de seguir o passo acima) será impresso:

```
'cookie_na_raiz' => string 'Este cookie foi criado na raiz do site' (length=38)
  'cookie_na_pasta_a' => string 'Este cookie foi criado na pasta a' (length=33)
```

Ao acessar o arquivo a.php pela segunda vez será impresso:

```
'cookie_na_raiz' => string 'Este cookie foi criado na raiz do site' (length=38)
  'cookie_na_pasta_a' => string 'Este cookie foi criado na pasta a' (length=33)
```

E por fim, ao acessar o arquivo b.php será impresso:

```
'cookie_na_raiz' => string 'Este cookie foi criado na raiz do site' (length=38)
      'cookie_na_pasta_a' => string 'Este cookie foi criado na pasta a' (length=33)
'cookie_na_pasta_b' => string 'Este cookie foi criado na pasta b' (length=33)
```

Isso mostra a diferença de visibilidade de acordo com o dominio em que o cookie foi criado. Reproduza esse exemplo e uma das duas situações deve estar acontecendo no seu codigo.

Comment: diz em que foi criada com sucesso mas quando as tento usar noutra pagina ela diz me que esta varia

Comment: o var_dump dá me que que existem 0 cookies

Comment: mas diz me que a cookie foi criada com sucesso

Comment: Mas e a parte de ser acessivel de acordo com o diretorio?

Comment: eu crio a cookie diz me que criou com sucesso e quando faço var_dump diz me que existem 0 cookies criadas